# How to build histogram in Julia

Tags: julia

Looking for function to build histogram, something like:

```
build_histogram(data = [1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.1], bins = 1:1:2) 
=> 
  [
    [1.1, 1.2], 
    [2.1, 2.1], 
  ]
```

P.S.

StatsBase allows to build histogram with data and bin ranges:

```
h = fit(Histogram, rand(100), 0:0.1:1.0)
```

But it doesn't provide the binned data itself. Or at the very least the way to use custom bin weights, in my case I need to calculate weight as a product `reduce(*, nth_bin_data)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
function partition(data, intervals)                                                                                
    ranges = intervals[1:end-1] .=> intervals[2:end]                                                               
    bins = [similar(data, 0) for _ in 1:length(ranges)]                                                                          
    for x in data                                                                                                  
        for (i, (a, b)) in pairs(ranges)                                                                           
            if a <= x < b                                                                                          
                push!(bins[i], x)                                                                                  
                break                                                                                              
            end                                                                                                    
        end                                                                                                        
    end                                                                                                            
    return bins                                                                                                    
end
```

Applied to your example:

```
julia> partition([1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.1], 1:1:3)
2-element Array{Array{Any,1},1}:
 [1.1, 1.2]
 [2.1, 2.1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a functional approach that uses `cut` from [CategoricalArrays.jl](https://juliadata.github.io/CategoricalArrays.jl/stable/).

```
using CategoricalArrays
using DataStructures # Needed to sort a dictionary.

data = [2.2, 1.1, 0.5, 1.7, 2.4]
interval = cut(data, 0:3)

scalar_dicts = map(Dict ∘ Pair, interval, data)

histogram_dict = merge(*, scalar_dicts...)
histogram_iterator = values(sort(histogram_dict))
```

And here is the same code in the REPL to illustrate the output from each step:

```
julia> interval = cut(data, 0:3)
5-element CategoricalArray{String,1,UInt32}:
 "[2, 3)"
 "[1, 2)"
 "[0, 1)"
 "[1, 2)"
 "[2, 3)"

julia> scalar_dicts = map(Dict ∘ Pair, interval, data)
5-element Array{Dict{CategoricalString{UInt32},Float64},1}:
 Dict("[2, 3)" => 2.2)
 Dict("[1, 2)" => 1.1)
 Dict("[0, 1)" => 0.5)
 Dict("[1, 2)" => 1.7)
 Dict("[2, 3)" => 2.4)

julia> histogram_dict = merge(*, scalar_dicts...)
Dict{CategoricalString{UInt32},Float64} with 3 entries:
  CategoricalString{UInt32} "[2, 3)" (3/3) => 5.28
  CategoricalString{UInt32} "[0, 1)" (1/3) => 0.5
  CategoricalString{UInt32} "[1, 2)" (2/3) => 1.87

julia> histogram_iterator = values(sort(histogram_dict))
Base.ValueIterator for a OrderedDict{CategoricalString{UInt32},Float64} with
3 entries. Values:
  0.5
  1.87
  5.28
```